# Create Multi-Level menu in Phalcon

Tags: phalcon

I'm trying to create a multi level menu in Phalcon framework from categories table. So far I did this:

MySql table categories:

```
id  parent          name                count_post
1     0         level_1_name_1              0                   
2     1         level_2_name_2              0
3     1         level_2_name_3              0   
4     2         level_3_name_4              60      
5     2         level_3_name_5              30
6     0         level_1_name_6              0
7     6         level_2_name_7              0
8     6         level_2_name_8              0
9     7         level_3_name_9              80
10    7         level_3_name_10             90
```

I need to create a html like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a>level_1_name_1</a>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a>level_2_name_2</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a>level_3_name_4</a></li>
               <li><a>level_3_name_5</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a>level_2_name_3</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a>level_1_name_6</a>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a>level_2_name_7</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a>level_3_name_9</a></li>
               <li><a>level_3_name_10</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a>level_2_name_8</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

In controller I get the data from model:

```
$menu = Menu::find();
$this->view->setVar('menu', $menu);
```

But how can I generate HTML in volt template to output like above? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

#### Model

```
class Menu extends ModelBase
{
    public $id;
    public $parent;
    public $name;
    public $count_post;

    public function getChilds()
    {
        $result = false;

        if($this->id) {
            $childs = self::find("parent = $this->id");
            if(count($childs)) {
                $result = $childs;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

---

#### View

```
{%- macro print_menu_level(menu_level_items) %}

    {%- for menu_item in menu_level_items %}

        {% if loop.first %}
            <ul>
        {% endif %}

        <li>

            <a>{{ menu_item.name }}</a>

            {% set next_menu_level_items = menu_item.getChilds() %}
            {% if next_menu_level_items %}
                {{ print_menu_level(next_menu_level_items) }}
            {% endif %}

        </li>

        {% if loop.last %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

    {%- endfor %}

{%- endmacro %}



{{ print_menu_level(root_menu_items) }}
```

---

#### Controller

```
$rootMenuItems = Menu::find('parent = 0');
$this->view->setVar('root_menu_items', $rootMenuItems);
```

*DISCLAIMER*: That's just an example I didn't tested this_